# Is it possible to force the value type in a YAML file using snakeYaml

Tags: yaml, snakeyaml

Currently I have a YAML file with a Key-Value pair specified as following:

```
name: bla
```

Is there a way to force the value to be a String without quoting "bla".

Comment: Since `bla` cannot be converted to a boolean, integer, float, datetime or date, you'll always get a string for `bla`.

Comment: @Anthon this is only true for the recommended schemas, not for deserializing to arbitrary data structures.

Comment: @flyx But it is true for the OPs YAML file in combination with snakeYAML,

Answer (score 1):

Sure, tag it:

```
name: !!str bla
```

You can also use the non-specific tag `!`, which will also resolve to a string:

```
name: ! bla
```

Comment: Tags are very limited, type accepted are float, int, string. You not have specific type as int32, int64, float64..

Comment: @AdrienParrochia You can register any tag you need via SnakeYAMLs API.